# How to create equivalent of appearance proxies in Cocoa Touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I can use appearance proxies to set properties for all controls of a given type in iOS. For example, I can say:

```
UIFont *futura = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:13];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:futura forKey:UITextAttributeFont];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

to make all my toolbar buttons use the Futura font.

I have my own custom control, a subclass of UIControl. Is there any way I can use the same technique to set some custom property unique to my control? Otherwise it's iterating through every single instance in the app setting properties directly. The question is, how do I create my own property proxy like the appearance proxy?

I can imagine setting up a singleton to hold the properties I care about, then have my controls call into this to get their values. That would appear to make it hard to handle the case where I want to set certain instances' properties differently to the global default, as I can with one or two of my UIBarButtonItems above. So then turns into a place where each new instance registers itself with the proxy, so the proxy can notify them of the settings if they change... But now I wonder if there's a better way? This seems complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs for `UIAppearanceContainer`.  You can have your subclass conform to the `UIAppearanceContainer` protocol and then mark the accessors with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` in your header file.   The example of the method declarations for `UIBarButtonItem` is like so:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *tintColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;

- (UIImage *)backButtonBackgroundImageForState:(UIControlState)state
         barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
- (void)setBackButtonBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage
    forState:(UIControlState)state
    barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```